# Opening multiple connections with the same database in separate threads simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, ms-access

While making a software monitoring system in C#, during our testing we encountered a problem with the database connections.

Even if we have declared multiple connections, the programs always throw an exception:

`"Current state connection is opening.:"`

Why is that?

Is it not possible to have two connections accessing the same database at the same time?

We are using Access Database.

```
private void UpdateListView(string query)
        {
            
                command.Connection = connection;
                insertinto = "1";
                command.CommandText = "Update ReaderUHF Set Identification = '" + insertinto + "' where EPC = '" + query + "'";
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                showdata(insertinto);

            
        }

//After 3 seconds. This thread is performed while the main thread is running

private void FinalLocation()
{
  command_1.Connection = connection_1;
                finaLoc = "Outside";
                command_1.CommandText = "Update ReaderUHF Set Location = '" + insertinto + "' where EPC = '" + query + "'";
                connection_1.Open();
                command_1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection_1.Close();
                
}
```

It throws an exception of `"Current connection state is opening"`.

Comment: Yes you can have many. Can we see some code?

Comment: Are you using only one connection to the database inside the transaction scope?

Comment: @JTWebMan Sorry, I don't have the code right now. But this is how it works. First is our main thread is continuously running which involves database operations, updating our database. After 3 seconds, there will be a second thread fired and will check database. And somehow, this is where we get our error.

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan No we are using different connections. But we only have one connection object which is our database.

Comment: Already included a code.

Comment: AFAIK MS Access is not a multi-user database.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So it's not capable of handling two simultaneous operations?

Comment: @JKLMToAnyone How is it [split](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/multiple-users-accessing-database/e6fa2335-69fd-4ec6-9e51-96a12c9d4c2e)?

Comment: you should do your `Open/Close` in a `try/finally` block in case an exception occurs.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what do you mean split? Do you mean by threads?

Comment: @JKLMToAnyone The word split was a link. I suggest you follow it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only share the connection string between the two threads. Though it has been a long time since I have seen Access used. Can you switch to Sqlite? if it is possible you should do it this way.

It is normally never a good idea to embed SQL code like this into a program but it sounds like this is just a school project so I would change the code to below. Just know in the real world you should do this but should add some Data Access layer like nHibernate or Entity Framework.

```
private void UpdateLocation(string newLocation, string query, string connectionString)
{
  //Using using statements calls close as well as dispose
  using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
  {
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
    {
      comm.Connection = conn;
      comm.CommandText = "Update ReaderUHF Set Location = @location where EPC = @query";
      //Always use Parameters to avoid SQL injection
      comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", newLocation);
      comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query", query);

      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}

private void UpdateIdentification(string identification, string query, string connectionString)
{
  using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
  {
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
    {
      comm.Connection = conn;
      comm.CommandText = "Update ReaderUHF Set Identification = @identification where EPC = @query";
      comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identification", identification);
      comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query", query);

      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

If the above code doesn't work you might have to use a lock to get around multiple connections. Something like this:

```
private object lockObj = new object();

private void UpdateListView(string query)
{
  command.Connection = connection;
  insertinto = "1";
  command.CommandText = "Update ReaderUHF Set Identification = '" + insertinto + "' where EPC = '" + query + "'";
  lock(lockObj)
  {
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
  }
  showdata(insertinto);              
}

//After 3 seconds. This thread is performed while the main thread is running

private void FinalLocation()
{
  command_1.Connection = connection_1;
  finaLoc = "Outside";
  command_1.CommandText = "Update ReaderUHF Set Location = '" + insertinto + "' where EPC = '" + query + "'";
  lock(lockObj)
  {
    connection_1.Open();
    command_1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection_1.Close();
  }            
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Whenever a user calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an
>   available connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available,
>   it returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When
>   the application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it
>   to the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once
>   the connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on
>   the next Open call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What if two different connections are open at the same time? Man, I'm sorry. I'm really new in C#.